# Mysql innodb query returning slow result

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb, mysql-slow-query-log

I have following query which is taking time.
Mytable type is innodb and have primary key on field tsh_id
I have also added index on transaction_Id field

following is implementation inside my database stored procedure.

```
 DECLARE lv_timestamp DATETIME(3);
    SET @lv_timestamp = NOW(3);

    IF(mycondition) then    
        SET @lv_Duration :=( SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP (@lv_timestamp)  - UNIX_TIMESTAMP ( `changedon` ) 
        FROM  `MyTable`         
        WHERE transaction_Id = _transaction_Id        
        ORDER BY tsh_id DESC
        LIMIT 1)        
    End if;
```

Please suggest any sort of improvement

Edit:

Explain to query says

```
"select_type":"SIMPLE",
"table":"MyTable",
"type":"ref",
"possible_keys":"IX_MyTable_Transaction",
"key":"IX_MyTable_Transaction",
"key_len":"98",
"ref":"const",
"rows":1,
"Extra":"Using where"
```

Comment: What does running `EXPLAIN` on the query have to say?

Comment: I have edited my question and give detail what explain says

Comment: I can't see right away from the explain that the query by itself should be slow.  Maybe someone else with more mysql optimization experience will have some input.

Comment: Please provide more info on what you mean by "slow" - how long does it take, how many times are you calling it, how many records are in the table, how long do you want it to take, etc.  Also, what data type is transaction_id?  The "Explain" output says the length is 98, so just curious how that is defined.

Comment: @Kamran Shahid - try to use a composite index with (transaction_Id, _wfrecord_Id) or (tsh_id , transaction_Id, _wfrecord_Id) . mysql can only use ONE INDEX in a query

Comment: _wfrecord_Id is the parameter  name for transaction_id field. Let me rename it for any confusion. tsh_id is not used in where clause? what's the advatange of making this primary key a composite key with transaction_id which already has it's own index

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE MyTable`

Comment: No @BerndBuffen , the only useful index is `(transaction_id, tsh_id)` -- start with the `=`, then add on the `ORDER BY`.  A slight improvement would be the 'covering index': `(transaction_id, tsh_id, changedon)`.

Comment: @KamranShahid - It is _sometimes_ advantageous to design the `PRIMARY KEY` for a range scan.  The table's records are arranged in `PRIMARY KEY` order, so if you need to scan a table in exactly the PK order, it will run faster than having that same key specified as a "secondary key".  In the case of `LIMIT 1`, the difference is quite insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have an index on MyTable.transaction_Id
2. Make sure you have the [innodb_buffer_pool_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) set to a decent value in your MySQL config

Comment: i have index on the MyTable.transaction_Id and i think innodb_buffer_pool_size is set around 1GB or 500 MB (My mysql server has 4 GB of Ram)

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain your primary key is not a clustered key (its might be null or not unique or you changed it at one point), because that would explain this behaviour, at least if `transaction_Id` isn't unique either (and otherwise you wouldn't need `limit 1`).

To improve this specific query, you can create the following index:

```
create index ix_mytable_transaction_id_tsh_id on MyTable (transaction_id, tsh_id desc);
```

Use `explain` again.

If it doesn't use the new key, force it:

```
SELECT ... FROM  `MyTable` force index(ix_mytable_transaction_id_tsh_id) ...
```

Comment: It's a Mysql innodb table. Mysql version is 5.6.27. tsh_id is a primary key with auto-increment. don't know. I have tried the composite index but it is almost redundant in my case as i am only searching on transaction_id. while tsh_id (primary key) is in order by clause

Comment: Could you post the results of: `show index from MyTable;`, `explain extended <the query>`, `show warnings;` (after explain extended), the number of rows in the resultset `SELECT count(*) FROM MyTable WHERE transaction_Id = _transaction_Id`, the time it takes to get that, and the time your query takes.